# ClipShape transition doesn't do anything

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to show a rectangle on screen with a custom circular transition. However, no matter what I do the rectangle will be clipped but there's no animation. It just plops on screen.

My code:

```
import SwiftUI


let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var rectangleShown = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Button(action: {
            
         
                rectangleShown = true
                
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Show Rectangle")
            }) .zIndex(0)
            
            
            if rectangleShown {
           
              Rectangle().frame(width: screenWidth*0.9, height: screenHeight*0.9)
               
                .transition(.iris)
                .zIndex(1)
              
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

The code for the custom transition (I found it online, but to me it appears to be fine):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScaledCircle: Shape {
    var animatableData: CGFloat

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let maximumCircleRadius = sqrt(rect.width * rect.width + rect.height * rect.height)
        let circleRadius = maximumCircleRadius * animatableData

        let x = rect.midX - circleRadius / 2
        let y = rect.midY - circleRadius / 2

        let circleRect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: circleRadius, height: circleRadius)

        return Circle().path(in: circleRect)
    }
}

struct ClipShapeModifier<T: Shape>: ViewModifier {
    let shape: T

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.clipShape(shape)
    }
}

extension AnyTransition {
    static var iris: AnyTransition {
        .modifier(
            active: ClipShapeModifier(shape: ScaledCircle(animatableData: 0)),
            identity: ClipShapeModifier(shape: ScaledCircle(animatableData: 1))
        )
    }
}
```

I have no idea why there's no animation. Well the first thing to consider is that transitions in swiftUI appear to somewhat inconsistently need an explicit animation attachment, so I tried these:

```
Rectangle().frame(width: screenWidth*0.9, height: screenHeight*0.9)
             
                   .transition(AnyTransition.iris.animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2)))
                   .zIndex(1)
```

and

```
Rectangle().frame(width: screenWidth*0.9, height: screenHeight*0.9)
             
                   .transition(AnyTransition.iris)
    .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2))
                   .zIndex(1)
```

and

```
Rectangle().frame(width: screenWidth*0.9, height: screenHeight*0.9)
    .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2))
                   .transition(AnyTransition.iris)
  
                   .zIndex(1)
```

as well as

```
withAnimation(.default) {
                rectangleShown = true
                }
```

There's no movement at all in all above cases. I also tried that with a custom opacity transition, also no animation. On the other hand, if I just do a simple (.slide) transition, it works. Could someone please have a look at what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It appears to be working in Xcode 12.3 / iOS 14.3 when added a `withAnimation` block in button action: `withAnimation { rectangleShown = true }`. What environment do you use?

Comment: I have the same issue, same code worked fine in iOS 13...